# RegEx for mathematical expressions

Tags: regex, bash, shell, unix, scripting

I am trying to run a comparison/search on user input in a bash script. I would like the user to be able to type in the function, the function is calculated and returned... How can I tell where in the string the group is located so I can keep things in order?

```
calculate 7 + 3
calculate 9.37 / 7.21
calculate 5 100 * 2.21
calculate 2783.34 – 25  

calculate -g hypotenuse 2.34 5.1   #-g argument for geometric
calculate -p 34.34/343             #-p argument for precision

calculate -g hypotenuse -p 2.34 5.1   #geometric and precision
```

edit: by group, I think I mean "token."

for example: things I know:
([-]*)([0-9]*)([.]*)([0-9]{1,}) defines integers or real numbers

([0-9]{1,}) defines integers

How do I retrieve the location of the token in the string, and how do I retrieve the operators?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow!  Its unclear what you're asking.  What have you tried?  Can you define what you mean by "group" in this context?

Comment: Maybe you just need [`bc`](http://www.basicallytech.com/blog/?/archives/23-command-line-calculations-using-bc.html) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said above you may use [`bc`](http://www.basicallytech.com/blog/?/archives/23-command-line-calculations-using-bc.html) to perform arithmetic operations. And likely, this would be the best solution because bash itself can only do integer math.

Neverneless if you wish to get integer and fractional parts of a float number you may use the following code:

```
a=123.456 # an example
a_int=${a%.*}
a_fr=${a#*.}
```

In your example each "group" is representing as a single argument, that is:

```
print_args() {
    for a in "$@"; do
        echo "arg=\"$a\""
    done
}
print_args 9.37 / 7.21
```

will print

```
arg="9.37"
arg="/"
arg="7.21"
```

Comment: +1 for figuring out what the OP probably meant to ask.  Since *"geometric"* and *"precision"* are mentioned in the question, it might be worth mentioning `bc -l` to load the "mathlib" and the `scale` variable.

Comment: Appreciate it! Sorry for the confusion- and thanks for expanding!